# dbunit maven plugin ordered set to true seemingly ignores tables

Tags: maven, dbunit

I am trying to export a portion of my db using the db-unit-maven plugin. I set the ordered flag set to true in my configuration so that I can re-import it avoiding integrity constraint violation.  I also specify what tables to export using the tables element inside the configuration. I pasted below an example of what I am trying to do. 
However, it exports additional tables that are unrelated in terms of constraints to those manually selected in the configuration. Does `<ordered>true</order>` cause the  list to be ignored? What am I missing?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
        <url>${it.datasource.url}</url>
        <username>${dbunit.username}</username>
        <password>${dbunit.password}</password>
        <dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>
        <skipOracleRecycleBinTables>true</skipOracleRecycleBinTables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>execute</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schema>${dbunit.username}</schema>
                <format>xml</format>
                <dest>target/dbunit/export.xml</dest>
                <tables>
                    <table name="TABLE_1" />
                    <table name="TABLE_2" />
                </tables>
                <ordered>true</ordered>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the syntax is wrong. The original pasted above returns a `NullPointerException` the correct syntax is pasted below and, as far as I can tell, it behaves as expected.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
        <url>${it.datasource.url}</url>
        <username>${dbunit.username}</username>
        <password>${dbunit.password}</password>
        <dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>
        <skipOracleRecycleBinTables>true</skipOracleRecycleBinTables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>execute</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schema>${dbunit.username}</schema>
                <format>xml</format>
                <dest>target/dbunit/export.xml</dest>
                <tables>
                    <table>
                       <name>TABLE_1</name>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                       <name>TABLE_2</name>
                    </table>
                </tables>
                <ordered>true</ordered>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```